# Convert to shamsi date to miladi date

Tags: c#

How I can to Convert Shamsi date to Miladi date ?
For example my value is **1374/06/27** and I want to convert this date to Miladi date **1995/09/18**.
I can't find function for convert Shamsi to Miladi .
What is this function?

Comment: I believe the Shamsi calendar is what I'd normally know as the Persian or Solar Hijri calendar - but I haven't heard of "Miladi" before, and I'm struggling to find any references. For the example you've given, it would work if "Miladi" is the Gregorian calendar system, but I don't want to assume that.

Comment: Same question for JavaScript is [here](/q/43850436)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This answer assumes that "Shamsi" means "Solar Hijri" or "Persian" calendar, and "Miladi" means "Gregorian Calendar". That's what my research suggests, though I haven't heard either term before.

## Using System.DateTime

If you're happy using the built-in types, you can perform the conversion quite simply like this:

```cs
Calendar persian = new PersianCalendar();
DateTime date = new DateTime(1374, 6, 27, persian);
Console.WriteLine(date.Year); // 1995
Console.WriteLine(date.Month); // 9
Console.WriteLine(date.Day); // 18
```

Basically `DateTime` is *always* in the Gregorian calendar system, even if you construct a value using a different calendar system. (Note that just using `Console.WriteLine(date)` will convert it back into the default calendar system of your default culture, which is why I didn't do that in the same code.)

In the reverse direction, you'd need to use `persian.GetYear(date)` etc.

## Using NodaTime

Personally I'm [not a big fan of `System.DateTime` etc](https://blog.nodatime.org/2011/08/what-wrong-with-datetime-anyway.html) - and in my [NodaTime library](https://nodatime.org), when you specify a calendar system, that's part of the value itself. So you can construct a date with the Persian calendar system, and that's the calendar system it will use forever - but it's easy to convert it to a date in the Gregorian calendar system, and vice versa:

```cs
LocalDate persianDate = new LocalDate(1374, 6, 27, CalendarSystem.PersianArithmetic);
LocalDate gregorianDate = persianDate.WithCalendar(CalendarSystem.Gregorian);
```

Obviously *I* think it's worth using NodaTime for this clarity - and many other reasons - but the choice is yours.

Comment: thank you for your answer. how to i change this result to 1995/09/18

Comment: @SoheilaTarighi: That's a matter of formatting a date - there are *lots* of questions about that on Stack Overflow already. I'd strongly recommend specifying the invariant culture when you format, to make sure it doesn't convert it back to a different calendar system.

Answer (score 0):

Persia .NET Core is a class library to convert Persian, Gregorian, and Arabic (Hijri) dates to each other. This library has been developed based on .NET Core 3.1

**Converting Gregorian to Shamsi**

```
Persia.SolarDate solarDate = Persia.Calendar.ConvertToPersian(DateTime.Now);
// getting the simple format of persian date
string str = solarDate.ToString();
```

**Converting Shamsi to Gregorian**

```
DateTime ConvertToGregorian(SolarDate solarDate)
DateTime ConvertToGregorian(LunarDate lunarDate)
DateTime ConvertToGregorian(int year, int month, int day, DateType dateType)
DateTime ConvertToGregorian(int year, int month, int day, int hour, int minute, int
second, DateType dateType)
```

more details and download from [here](https://github.com/shahabfar/Persia-.NET-Core)