# .Net 6 : Convert string Shamsi date to Gregorian in Asp.Net Core?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-6.0

I receive a date that the user enters in the input box as a string, for example: `1402/02/30`

How can I change this date to Gregorian and save it in the database with datetime format?

I also saw the link below, but the format of the date is different?

[Sample](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62642715/convert-to-shamsi-date-to-miladi-date)